# Touble create Apache virtual host

Tags: apache2, virtualhost

I have `000-default.conf` in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`. I want to create a new virtual host `myserver`. So I duplicate `000-default.conf` and rename it `000-myserver.conf`. Inside this file:

```
#NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myserver 
    ServerAdmin webmaster@myserver
    DocumentRoot /home/user479/myserver/www

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Then on terminal I restart apache and run `$ sudo a2ensite myserver`. But it gives me this error: `ERROR: Site dropbox does not exist!`

Comment: Try going through this tutorial:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo mv /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-myserver.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/myserver.conf
sudo a2ensite myserver.conf
```

Or

```
sudo a2ensite 000-myserver
```

---

Since the config file you created is called `000-myserver.conf`, then the site you want to enable is `000-myserver` not just `myserver`.

As a personal preference, I would suggest renaming it `myserver.conf` i.e. remove the starting `000-` from the file name. It's easier to remember when having multiple virtual hosts, and needing to stop/enable one of them. Since you wouldn't need to remember what is the number preceding the file.

The use of that number prefix is mostly to make apache load the Virtual Hosts at specific order.